# distance based classification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 dimensional array of integers (~4000 x 6000 x 3) that I need to classify in a particular way. I'm hoping for something like a k-means clustering method, but instead of inputting the number of clusters I would like to input the maximum radius of a cluster.

Said another way, given a sphere of a defined size, I would like to find the minimum number of non-empty spheres that will cover all the data and classify the points accordingly.

Though I have little knowledge of the field, I have been looking into clustering algorithms for a little while and have not found one that accomplishes this.

For example, given a random dataset:

```
import numpy as np

randomArray = np.random.rand(10,10,3)*500

Out[8]: 
array([[[ 256.68932025,  153.07151992,  196.19477623],
        [  48.05542231,  346.1289173 ,  327.44694932],
        [ 427.87340594,  197.26882283,  402.41558648],
        [ 192.50462233,  408.31800086,   81.66016443],
        [  64.15373494,   34.96971099,  446.55362458]],

       [[ 376.55003794,   70.09514697,  242.08947306],
        [ 194.86207829,  379.90969257,  439.47043484],
        [ 102.99922513,   98.57769429,  415.5059223 ],
        [ 464.65318671,  223.60061654,  417.52758666],
        [  53.68383153,  205.32517075,  299.83858164]],

       [[ 364.80957874,   14.26150931,  264.01568428],
        [ 295.75617954,  107.52678922,   87.89830525],
        [  57.90617865,  409.54132373,   54.36940482],
        [ 217.35951975,  345.7892723 ,  301.07031811],
        [ 295.98999071,   27.17772152,  182.58776469]],

       [[ 291.69513153,  466.03218019,  279.25794618],
        [ 179.60152364,  161.64966386,  269.34221176],
        [ 374.78609278,  259.18286321,  459.8037004 ],
        [ 458.51249648,   87.05600447,  268.12588338],
        [ 152.54500603,  472.36773898,    1.15894726]],

       [[  35.43731854,  163.42770568,  131.77683448],
        [  14.36039625,  390.33409364,  314.56443073],
        [  71.47211566,  109.78613335,  345.57021076],
        [  74.62340632,  328.51303903,  341.97344285],
        [ 205.02121677,  235.71812371,   32.91252756]]])
```

and a maximum radius

```
R = 35
```

I would like to output a 2D array of the same height and width, with labels that represent the sphere each point in the 3D array was classified in. No two points with the same label should have a euclidian distance greater than the maximum radius, no sphere should be empty and the algorithm should use the minimum number of spheres possible to accomplish this.

Comment: This looks like 3D so by circles, I'm assuming you actually mean spheres? An interesting problem. Do you have any sample code or a [mcve] you can share? You may also want to try asking this over at [datascience.se].

Comment: What is the meaning of those 2 dimensions (4000 x 6000)? Every point being a point in 3d and covering these with spheres sounds ok. But why those extra dimensions (instead of a single sample dimension) which also should be kept? (additionally: clustering is unsupervised in general while classification is supervised; the non-empty rule is redundant)

Comment: Also: a point can't be covered by multiple spheres, right, or else your classification rule is incompletely specified. (although i doubt it's a good design-decision as the number of sphere will grow a lot in general). The whole classification-thing / and potential overlaps makes this problem NP-hard *i think*.

Comment: @sascha Right, spheres should not overlap! Though I'm not sure I understand your first comment

Comment: I don't think the problem is fully specified yet because the criterion used to evaluate the clustering is missing. For example, are you interested in assigning the points to `K` clusters such that `K` is as small as possible with the constraint that each point belongs to exactly one cluster? Do you have other constraints on `K`. As an aside, the optimisation for this problem is probably difficult because the loss function is unlikely to be smooth.

Comment: And now for something completely different, you have output a result from `np.random.rand(5,5,3)*500` instead of `(10,10,3)`.

Comment: Try taking a look at circle packing: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html

Comment: @sascha I'm pretty sure this type of problem (at least for minmal clusters) can be reformulated as a n-d map coloring problem, which is indeed NP-hard.

Comment: @asheets _"Right, spheres should not overlap!"_ If I understand correctly, given a fixed radius that is not always possible. If you densely fill a few sphere volumes worth of space with points some will fall in the unavoidable dead space.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: He talks about an array of integers. In the worst case, he puths a tiny shpere around each gridpoint - at least if I understand the problem properly

Comment: @asheets: Is there a particular reason you talk about arrays of shape N * M * 3? If I understand properly, the task is to handle a list of points in 3dimensions, i.e. a N*3 array

Comment: @MarkusDutschke I thought sphere radius was fixed at `35` in which case integerness won't save us. I didn't mean dense in the mathematically strict sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variation of Affinity based clustering in scikit learn; [basic guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation), [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-affinity-propagation-py), [cluster object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html#sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation).  You will have to modify the distance metric / matrix to ensure the sphere radius is less than the max radius.  Affinity and Density Based (DBSCAN) clustering are the only unsupervised machine learning methods that do not require a predefined number of clusters.

[Affinity Clustering Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf5rF.png)

The reason I don't recommend DBSCAN is there will be points that are not part of a cluster.  With Affinity clustering all the points will be part of a cluster.  Affinity clustering can take a long time to converge, O(N^2 * T) where 'N' is the number of samples and 'T' is the number of iterations to converge.  The 'signal' from Affinity clustering can represent your radius.  Since the default `affinity`, which represents how the signal is calculated between points, is a variation of euclidean distance you have a jump start on calculating the clusters.

> affinity : string, optional, default='euclidean'
>
> Which affinity to use. At the moment precomputed and euclidean are
>   supported. euclidean uses the negative squared euclidean distance
>   between points.

Additionally, you can weight different points using the `preference` input.  As you iterate / converge on the number of clusters you will have look at the `affinity_matrix_` and `cluster_centers_` attributes to determine if all the points are within your max radius.  The preference for each point can change as you iterate through the different variations of clustering to indicate which cluster the point is most likely to be a part of.

> preference : array-like, shape (n_samples,) or float, optional
>
> Preferences for each point - points with larger values of preferences
>   are more likely to be chosen as exemplars. The number of exemplars, ie
>   of clusters, is influenced by the input preferences value. If the
>   preferences are not passed as arguments, they will be set to the
>   median of the input similarities.

If you wanted to try DBSCAN the three main metrics are the EPS (max distance between two samples), minimum number of points to make a cluster and the distance metric [DBSCAN cluster object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN), [basic guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan), [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py).

[DBSCAN Clustering Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWnXF.png)

You may not have to iterate as much through DBSCAN as you would with Affinity.  You would be able to test quickly if the max distance choosen is a viable option since the cluster label in DBSCAN will be `-1` if the sample is not part of a cluster at that distance.  Your memory consumption will be high with large datasets.

There are three types of points / samples in the DBSCAN algorithm:

- Core Sample:

> a sample in the dataset such that there exist `min_samples` other
>   samples within a distance of `eps`

- Fringe Sample:

> are samples that are neighbors of a core sample in the cluster but are
>   not themselves core samples; translation is this sample is within the `eps`
>   distance but doesn't have the `min_samples` surrounding it (less than
>   `eps` distance)

- Outlier:

> is not a core sample, and is at least `eps` in distance from any core
>   sample

The DBSCAN clusters are defined by the core samples only.  This can get confusing but scikit learn does a pretty good job of explaining the algorithm.

I don't think there is an easy implementation to your problem.  Both Affinity and DBSCAN have their pro's and con's.  I think Affinity would be your best bet initially because DBSCAN can get confusing and may give you a memory error depending on the size of your sample matrix.

I hope this helps.  It's a very interesting question.  I would try a variation of Affinity to initially solve this problem.

Comment: You could also try using `affinity = "precomputed"` and precompute your affinity matrix so that affinities less than `-R**2` are set to `-np.inf`

Comment: Also it seems like [`AffinityPropagation` accepts `csr` sparse precomputed similarities](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/cluster/affinity_propagation_.py#L294), so that would be a direction to go in as well..

Answer (score 0):

**Potential Approximate Solution**

I'm not certain this problems is tractable without some additional constraints but if you're willing to live with an approximation I think I might see a solution.

Consider each point in space as having a sphere of influence `R = 35`.  You can then compute a matrix (upper triangular) with the distance between all points.  If the distance from Pi to Pj is less than R, you consider that point within the sphere of influence.  You now have a `set` of influenced points for each point. The second step is to iterate through and select who's sets to include in the final solution.  One method would be to select the most "influential" point, deduct its set of influenced points from the other sets and repeat until you've included everything.

There are a few issues with this approach that may or may-not be important...

1. The center of your sphere may include more points if it's not located on one of your points (picture 2 points that are 30 units apart).  If your data is reasonably well distributed or clustered this might yield acceptable results.
2. I don't believe iteratively selecting the sphere with the most "influenced" points is guaranteed to yield the most optimal solution.  (Picture a dense cluster of points with one point just outside to the right and one to the left.  This method would yield 3 spheres where a better solution might include all points with only 2 spheres.)

If an approximation seems like something that might work for your project, we can discuss specifics of coding up a realistic test cast and trying it out.